# How to request data from coinmarketcap API using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm going crazy about trying to fetch json using the CMC-API. I just want to make a simple ajax request to fetch a JSON. My code is very simple:

```
<div id="out"></div>

<script>
    $.getJSON('https://sandbox-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=b54bcf4d-1bca-4e8e-9a24-22ff2c3d462c&id=1', function(r) {
        $("#out").html("test");
    });
</script>
```

The callback is not being executed. Looking into the network traffic reveals that the request has a 200 status code but an empty response payload. Using the url in a browser returns the requested data. Using another url in the code (for example: http://time.jsontest.com/) works fine but the CMC-url doesn't work in the AJAX request. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the issue is CORS - that API doesn't allow requests from browsers - you'll need to make the request from *your* server ... `http://time.jsontest.com/` works because it does allow CORS

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for that info. I just found out that coingecko.com offers a free API as well.. No API-keys whatsoever. I'm gonna use that one... F*ck CMC.. https://www.coingecko.com/en/api#explore-api